# TFS - Get test in a static "suiteId"

Tags: tfs

I got on TFS this setup:

- Static group [SG1]

  - [t1]
  - [t2]
  - [t3]

I'd like to make a query that give me access to the t1,t2,t3 under the SG1 group in order to make other operation. Usually i would make a "tree" query and set filter the father/son relationship.

[image]

But since it's a static group, it got no child to be displayed. 
Is there a workaround to retrive all elements contained in a suiteId?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Test Suites - Get Test Cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test%20%20suites/get%20test%20cases?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to get all test cases in a suite.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Plans/{planId}/suites/{suiteId}/testcases?api-version=5.0
```